# Parse Json in Java not working

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, arrays

I have the following json:

```
{
    "count" : "1567",
    "program" : ["NDBC Meteorological\/Ocean", "International Partners"],
    "owner" : ["NDBC", "Alaska Ocean Observing System"],
    "station" : [{
            "id" : "00922",
            "lat" : "30",
            "lon" : "-90",
            "name" : "OTN201 - 4800922"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need just to get `station` information like the `id`, `lat`, `lon`, `name` etc. But I cannot get it to work,  here's my code:

```
//////response_str is the json string///////

  JSONArray  pages =  new JSONArray(response_str);
            for (int i = 0; i < pages.length(); ++i) {
                JSONObject rec = pages.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject jsonPage =rec.getJSONObject("station");
                String name= jsonPage.getString("name");
                System.out.println(name);
            }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, Regards

Comment: How is it not working? Any error? Exception what?

Comment: an exception that print the whole response_str on the log cat

Comment: `jsonPage.getString("name");` probably fails because `station` is an array of objects, even though it has length 1, and not a single object...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`station` is `JSONArray` instead of `JSONObject` so you will need to first get JSONArray from main JSONObject then extract all `id,lat,lon,..` from `JSONObject`. change your code as:

```
JSONArray  pages =  new JSONArray(response_str);
  for (int i = 0; i < pages.length(); ++i) {
      JSONObject rec = pages.getJSONObject(i);
      JSONArray jsonPage =rec.getJSONArray("station");
      // get JSONObject
      JSONObject jsonstation =jsonPage.getJSONObject(0);
      String name= jsonstation.getString("name");
      System.out.println(name);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks i got it to work using part of this code...appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

The root is a `JSONObject` not a `JSONArray` and it contains, three `JSONArray` named `programm`, `station` and `owner` and the `count` field. You  should change your code accordingly with the JSON structure

Comment: Thanks, this gave me an idea of what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the outside loop at all

```
JSONObject jMain = new JSONObject( response_str);
JSONArray jStationList =jMain.getJSONArray("station");
JSONObject jStation =jStationList.getJSONObject(0);

String name= jsonstation.getString("name");
```

..etc

Answer (score 0):

You're issue is that you're referring to the source string as a JSONArray when it is instead a JSONObject (brackets on the outside would indicate that is an array).  The following gets the name of the station.

```
JSONObject  pages =  new JSONObject(response_str);

for (int i = 0; i < pages.length(); ++i) 
{
   JSONArray stationInfo =rec.getJSONArray("station");
   String name= stationInfo.getString("name");
   System.out.println(name);
}
```